# Should i delete projects folder after uploading it to GitHub?

Tags: github

it's my first question, i dunno how dumb, sorry in advance. what I wonder is, say, you have tons of files and projects on your computer and say i have created a new project and uploaded to a new repo. does it make sense to delete it after from my computer, like if I were to make changes on that repo i should be able to copy it to my computer back from github right?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete or remove your project from your device after putting it on GitHub, there is no problem. After that, if you ever need the project, you can clone it and use it.

But it looks better if done like this:

First create a project and put it on github but instead of deleting it from the device you can push it to github when the project is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can delete your project folder after uploading to GitHub, you can copy the code back to your system whenever you want.
There is an option to download your code as zip file as well, or you could use git to do that.  And don't feel bad for yourself, we all start like this.. Good Luck For your future.

Comment: thanks :)) i hope i'll be able to response questions too

Comment: Sure you will be.